# Standing/sitting Shtender recommendation

Tags: product-recommendation

Does anyone here have a recommendation for a sturdy, high quality, table-top Shtender that can easily switch between standing and sitting heights?
Also good would be a floor shtender with a detachable top to use for tabletop sitting....
Ideally obtainable in Israel.

Comment: This question is not about Judaism, but about paraphernalia useful for holding books.

Comment: @mevaqesh an object very commonly used specifically for Jewish books, and therefore relevant and applicable specifically to Jewish needs in terms of learning

Comment: I agree. However, questions that are relevant to Jewish needs, but not to Judaism itself, are off topic. Similarly, if for example, Jews tend to have higher birthrates and therefore have more young people, making it harder for younger girls to marry older guys, questions asking for dating advice remain off topic.

Comment: @mevaqesh then how are product recommendations ever on topic? A sefer is not about Judaism, it's a Jewish need but there are plenty sefer recommendations on here.

Comment: "A sefer is not about Judaism". The Bible isn't about Judaism?

Comment: @mevaqesh where to find a good mishna brura in English doesn't seem much different than this. About Judaism would be asking ABOUT the mishna brura, not where to buy one.

Comment: I agree that there are many questions in the site that have not yet been removed that are not consistent with the described goal of this site.

Comment: @mevaqesh Alright, so we'll see what happens. I'm going to post on meta about this.

Comment: It has already been discussed on Meta. By none other than myself. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/general-knowledge-relating-to-judaism-how-related. Follow links there to earlier version of question.

Comment: @mevaqesh and looks like I already upvoted an answer there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.google.com/search?q=metal+shtender&client=ms-android-metropcs-us&sa=X&biw=360&bih=559&tbs=vw:l&tbm=shop&prmd=sinv&srpd=10811205187816261255&prds=num:1,of:1,epd:1198148667945920393,cid:10356735344672919325&ved=0ahUKEwi93oiu9LHKAhXBPxoKHV1IDg8QgjYIngIwDA&ei=ghecVr2VO8H_aN2QuXg) one seems like the type I've used in the past. Pretty sturdy, detachable table top piece. Made out of metal. Ships worldwide, but not cheap. This price is pretty standard for this item.

However, due to the intricate moving parts, I would not recommend leaving it in a beis medrash full of young bochrim. It wouldn't last too long there. But at home, it's perfect.

Comment: Do you have a specific brand you're familiar with?

Comment: No. Never seen a label. But it looks the same. Usually specialty items like this that look so exactly the same are actually manufactured in the same place but sold under different labels. So names and labels wouldn't concern me.

Comment: Is the table top part easy to take on and off frequently?

Comment: It has spring loaded pins. Pull em out to take out the top. That is actually the weakest part of this design, imho. That's the part I've seen broken most. But again, those were in public places where many people who weren't careful were using them. Just something to think about if that is THE game changer for you.