# Shtender Recommendations

Tags: product-recommendation, shtender

Can someone recommend a shtender to hold a volume of Gemara? I am looking for one with the following features -

1. Adjusts for angle
2. Adjusts for height
3. Has page holders to keep the pages open
4. Fits a standard size gemara volume
5. Sits on a table

Comment: In Israel or the US ?

Comment: As @Dov mentioned, page holders aren't a common feature but you can buy spring clips in pretty much any shape or size imaginable and add them to your shtender afterwards

Comment: Related (and maybe duplicate): [Standing/sitting Shtender recommendation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67351/11501)

Comment: Depending on your budget, you can hire someone to make a custom shtender to your specifications.

Answer (score 1):

So there are several - although page holders are not necessarily a common feature.

(Just as an aside, it is worth noting that there is a limitation with shtenders that can be adjusted for height/angle and that is, that since they are made to move you don't often find them with room for storage like you would with the static table top shtenders e.g. [here](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/tall-table-top-shtender-with-lock/29305))

This [one](https://www.eichlers.com/wooden-2-tone-book-stand-shtender-2-position-with-silver-plate-am58364-2.html) is a standard model, with there being many variations on a theme e.g. [here](https://www.eichlers.com/elegant-wood-shtender-with-3-levels-art43330.html) and [here](https://www.eichlers.com/lux-lucite-foldable-tabletop-shtender-with-silver-metal-sbs-f-s.html):

[image]

It has different incline positions and can be adjusted for height. It fits a Gemara and is made to sit on a table.

---

**EDIT**

[This](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/304465483815?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&itemid=304465483815&targetid=293946777986&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=1006886&poi=&campaignid=17116423086&mkgroupid=134652533165&rlsatarget=pla-293946777986&abcId=9300856&merchantid=561567705&gclid=CjwKCAjwyryUBhBSEiwAGN5OCNMlarT05wKYOOLKtSceSPpHTNtzuPDdyxBltQGiGMyJyrBQ8_4wWRoCwF4QAvD_BwE) is not a "shtender" per se, but it fulfils all your critera...
You can alter height and incline, it goes on a table and has page holders.

Comment: Thank you. Do any of these come with page holders?

Comment: Personally I have not seen one with page holders on shtenders that adjust by height but only on incline alone e.g. https://thefrumshoppingmall.com/products/xl-large-size-bamboo-book-stand-cookbook-holder-reading-desk-bookrest-with-5-adjustable-height-foldable-tray-and-page-paper-clip-portable-sturdy-bookstands-for-textbook-magazine-music-books-recipe